# Google Recaptcha v3 gives invalid response

Tags: php, recaptcha

Google Recaptcha v3 alvays gives invalid response.

**Looks like problem in .tpl file.**

What I did wrong? Please help if somebody has an experience with it.

Site on Opencart
PHP 7.4

Installed by compressor command - composer require google/recaptcha "^1.2"

Google Recaptcha v3 Version: 1.2.4

https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/76fb886fa71e6654de86a0bc5f77ef8101b55f17

**print_r($recaptcha); ---->**

```
  ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha Object
        (
[secret:ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha:private] => bhfbj4bfi48y8fhu9023ijr4fnhu5fbnjf5eofj5nf5inf5in5
[requestMethod:ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha:private] => ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post Object
(
[siteVerifyUrl:ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post:private] => https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
)
        
        [hostname] => my_syte.com
        [action] => homepage
        [threshold] => 0.5
```

**print_r($resp); ----->**

```
ReCaptcha\Response Object
(
[success:ReCaptcha\Response:private] =>
[errorCodes:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => Array
(
[0] => invalid-input-response
[1] => hostname-mismatch
[2] => action-mismatch
[3] => score-threshold-not-met
)

[hostname:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
[challengeTs:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
[apkPackageName:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
[score:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
[action:ReCaptcha\Response:private] =>
```

**In controler file plase code:**

```
require __DIR__ . '/appengine-https.php';

//reCAPTCHA PHP client library
require_once '/root/www/site-root/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/autoload.php';


//Secret key
$siteKey = 'My key';
$secret = 'My key';

// Copy the config.php.dist file to config.php and update it with your keys
    $config = include __DIR__ . '/config.php';
if ($siteKey == '' && is_readable(__DIR__ . '/root/www/site-root/wwww/config.php')) {
    $siteKey = $config['v3']['site'];
    $secret = $config['v3']['secret'];
}
// reCAPTCHA supports 40+ languages listed here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language
$lang = 'en';
$lang = 'ru';

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);

$resp = $recaptcha
    ->setExpectedHostname('my_site.com')
    ->setExpectedAction('homepage')
    ->setScoreThreshold(0.5)
    ->verify('token', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
    //$this->error_msg = 'ReCaptcha field is required.';
   
}

**if ($resp->getScore() < 0.1) {
    header('Location: success.htm');**
    exit();
   //$recaptchaErrors = $response->getErrorCodes();



} else {
    // otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
    //header('Location: success.htm');
    //exit();

}
```

**In .tpl file plased code:**

```
<?php echo $header; ?><div class="container">

<!--<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>-->
    <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
    <?php $column_left  = trim($column_left);
    $column_right  = trim($column_right); ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-18'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-24'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
        <body>
  <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="contact-info">
      <div class="right" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <h2><?php echo $text_contact; ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
    <span><?php echo $entry_name; ?></span><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />

    <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_name; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <span><?php echo $entry_email; ?></span><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />

    <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <span><?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?></span><br />
    <textarea class="form-control" name="enquiry" cols="40" rows="10"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>

    <?php if ($error_enquiry) { ?>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_enquiry; ?></span>


    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <br/>
      <div class="left"><input id="token" type="hidden" name="token"></div>
       <div class="buttons">
      <div class="left"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="submit" value="<?php echo $button_send; ?>" class="btn" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=site_key' ></script>
  <script>
      function onClick(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
  console.log(token);
  document.getElementById('token').value = token
  });
  });</script>
          </body>
        <?php echo $content_bottom; ?>
      <style>
      input[type="submit"]{
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      margin-left: 365px;
      padding: 7px 25px;
      }
      </style>
    </div></div></div>

<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: From the PHP manual on the [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement - `"it's possible to return values from included files"` so where you assign `$config = include __DIR__ . '/config.php';` does that file issue a valid `return` statement? Also, your `.tpl` file has invalid HTML - there is no opening `body` tag nor opening `form` tag - unless you have not shown all of it?!

Comment: print_r($recaptcha);  ----> ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha Object
(
    [secret:ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha:private] => bhfbj4bfi48y8fhu9023ijr4fnhu5fbnjf5eofj5nf5inf5in5
    [requestMethod:ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha:private] => ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post Object
        (
            [siteVerifyUrl:ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post:private] => https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
        )

    [hostname] => my_syte.com
    [action] => homepage
    [threshold] => 0.5
)

Comment: Responce is empty.  print_r($resp); -----> ReCaptcha\Response Object
(
    [success:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
    [errorCodes:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => invalid-input-response
            [1] => hostname-mismatch
            [2] => action-mismatch
            [3] => score-threshold-not-met
        )

    [hostname:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
    [challengeTs:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
    [apkPackageName:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
    [score:ReCaptcha\Response:private] => 
    [action:ReCaptcha\Response:private] =>

Answer (score 0):

You are checking response with ($resp->getScore() < 0.1) but response says [threshold] => 0.5.

Also, you send action expection on JS but in PHP >setExpectedAction('contact')

**Probably this**: in tpl file, site key is not filled in url in script tag

Comment: Unfortunately key is filled.